# Cant retrieve file from vue axios to laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

So I am doing axios post request from Vue to Laravel and I have form with some inputs and file upload.
This is my axios call:

```
axios.post('/dashboard/api/partners', this.model.$, )
     then(response => console.log(this.model.$))
}
```

And my submitted `this.model.$` looks like this:
[image]

And then I try to get `logo: File` with `$request->file('logo')->store('images')`, but I get `"Call to a member function store() on null"`

Comment: what does your request->all() look like when returned via json
            
return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $request->all(),
                'message' =>  ''
            ]);
console.log(response.data.data) in your axios then response


I also think you need to use FormData when submitting files or images
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-54-upload-files-with-axios

Answer (score 0):

Pass the following headers

```
 const config = {
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
     }
}
```

Then post it

```
axios.post('/dashboard/api/partners', this.model.$, config)
     then(response => console.log(this.model.$))
}
```